# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) in Swift code. Why?

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing, soap

I'm trying to parse a XML, but when I put the string in a label or textfield it gives me error. Why? I'm not in Viewcontroller.swift, but in another class. And I need to change the label/textfield text with the result of XML parsing.

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(lobj_Request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")
        let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()


        if error != nil
        {
            println("Error: " + error.description)
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}


var currentElementName:NSString = ""

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    currentElementName = elementName
}


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?)
{
    if currentElementName == "HelloAppleAndroidResult"
    {
        self.txtResult.text = string
    }
}
```

The problem is:

```
self.txtResult.text = string
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to safely unwrap string since you have declared it as optional in your parser method signature.

```
if let string = string {
  self.txtResult.text = string
}
```

It also means that string was nil at this point – and your signature says: it's okay to be nil.
Also, string is not a really good name for any parameter – I'd suggest to change it to something more concept-related.

You could also use the nil-coalescing operator here. It would require you to provide an alternative for the assignment (which is the point of that operator). The alternative can't be optional.

```
self.textResult.text = string ?? alternativeString
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question **I'm not in Viewcontroller.swift, , but in another class**, i strongly doubt `self.textResult` might be `nil` in that class. Put a break point above this line

```
self.txtResult.text = string
```

and check the value of `self.textResult`. You can use the debugger to check using `po self.textResult`